# How can I update entity with its children? Patch method doesn't work

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api-odata, odata-v4

I must update my entity with its children list as shown here:

```
 public class Entity1 
 { 
    int Id{get;set;} 
    ObservableCollection<Child1> ChildrenList {get;set;} 
    string Name{get;set;}
 }

public class Child1
{
    string Nome{get;set;}
    string Cognome {get;set;}
}
```

I implemented patch method in this way:

```
[AcceptVerbs("PATCH", "MERGE")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch([FromODataUri] int key, Delta<Entity1> entityDelta)
{

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            var entity = await Context.Entity1.FindAsync(key);
            if (entity == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            entityDelta.Patch(entity);

            try
            {
                await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Updated(entity);
}
```

but when I try to call it from fiddler in this way:

```
Url: http://localhost/odata4/Entity1(1)/  with patch request

Request Headers: Content-Type: application/json

Request Body: 
{
Name: "pippo2",
ChildrenList:[{
Nome: "Test",
Cognome: "Pippo"
}]
}
```

It gives an error in Model.isValid Property and specified return this error:

> Cannot apply PATCH to navigation property 'ChildrenList' on entity
>   type 'Entity1'.

How can I solve it? Is the patch method the correct method to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[OData V4 spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc406398329) says for update an entity:

*The entity **MUST NOT** contain related entities as inline content. It MAY contain binding information for navigation properties. For single-valued navigation properties this replaces the relationship. For collection-valued navigation properties this adds to the relationship.*

So, You can use:

1. Update the child:

   Patch/Put: ~/Child1s(...)
2. Update parent

   Patch/Put: ~/Entity1s(...)
3. Update the relateship between parent and child:

   PATCH/PUT ~/Entity1s(...)/ChildrenList/$ref

with entity reference links content.

Comment: How can i try it in Fiddler? 
What's the request body for Content-type: application/json ? 

I try with this but fail:
`{
ChildrenList: [{ "uri": "http://localhost/odata4/ChildrenList(1)"}]
}`

Comment: There's a test case that you can refer to:

https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/test/E2ETest/WebStack.QA.Test.OData/Singleton/SingletonTest.cs#L271-L277

The related controller is https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/test/E2ETest/WebStack.QA.Test.OData/Singleton/PartnersController.cs#L69-L92